# Swift : getting an error retrieving image from url

Tags: swift

I'm trying to retrieve an image from a url but for some reason it will not not display the image

```
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://cdn.businessoffashion.com/site/uploads/2014/09/Karl-Lagerfeld-Self-Portrait-Courtesy.jpg") {
    if let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
        print("work")
        imageUIView.image = UIImage(data: data)
    } else {
        print("dontwork")
    }
}
```

Comment: Not having any issues. Image is getting retrieved properly. Post the code where you're trying to display the image.

Comment: Is there any kind of error? I tried with your code and working fine here. Have you make proper `IBOutlet` connection with imageView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting  iOS 9.0 or OS X v10.11, you may be running into Apple's *App Transport Security*.  Running your code while targeting these operating system versions, the following output will be displayed int console:

`App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.`

[Apple now requires](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33) you to only access files via `https` or to allow non-https (ie. `http`) exceptions via `info.plist`.

If you haven't already, I'd suggest updating your `info.plist`.

You can do this on a per domain basis, or allow arbitrary loading of non-https url.

For example, update your `info.plist` with the following keys/values:

[image]

If this is your issue, once your `info.plist` is updated, your code should work.